# Change tbody element when hover thead element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change `tbody` element on hover `thead` element via CSS only? I searched the subject, but there was about inner div elements of parent div only.

```css
thead th {
  background-color: wheat;
}

thead th:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

thead th:hover tbody td {
  background-color: red;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
   <table>
     <thead><tr><th>qqqqq</th></tr></thead>
     <tbody><tr><td>wwwww</td></tr></tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Not tested but try `.one table thead:hover + tbody` and give thead and tbody a background while th and td have a transparent background.

Comment: @bron i can't get it work, with class names :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```css
thead th {
  background-color: wheat;
}

thead th:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

thead:hover + tbody td {
  background-color: red;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
   <table>
     <thead><tr><th>qqqqq</th></tr></thead>
     <tbody><tr><td>wwwww</td></tr></tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i have classes? for example my th element and td element has the same class name? and i make hover on class name not just th:hover

Comment: If you want to act on hovering over a specific cell, you would need js.

Comment: @Nar Jovan. I'm not sure how you have it in mind but try this.
The target in this example is the 3rd cell on the 5th row when hovering the thead.
`thead:hover + tbody tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(3) { background-color: red; }`